# PageURL Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, query-string

I have made a website in which once user logs in a encrypted query string is made and passed along the pages to authenticate the user if the sessions fails. But now the problem is if i paste the url to another computer  it simply recreates the sessions from the encrypted query string and the user can move along the website.

I just dont want to remove the query string because it is used in the app extensively ...can u plz suggest how can i make this more secure and make urls pc dependent

Comment: Unfortunately you've probably opened a security hole that is going to be difficult to close without removing the dependence on the query string session.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities in your case:

1. You make sure that you use every available information about the browser part of your session and validate it every time (including remote-ip and similar). Be aware that this doesn't make it secure in any way, but perhaps you don't care OR
2. Use HTTPS and write the SessionID into an HTTPS only cookie as everybody else does.

Read more on the topic in msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178201.aspx